# How to check/uncheck dynamically in a JSP page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with JSP and Servlet. Below is my JSP form which has drop down list and checkbox list. As soon as I click `Access` button, my drop down list gets populated dynamically with all the email id's and also my checkbox list gets populated dynamically as well with all the item id's.

```
    <p id="one">
        <input type="button" class="btn-primary" id="per" value="Access"/>
    </p>

    <form id="form_permission" method="post" action="/test/">
        <h4>Welcome!</h4>

        <p> Users
            <select id="yes"></select>
        </p>

        <div id="id1" class="container"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
        <input type='hidden' name='action' value='per'>

    </form>
```

Below is my jquery for that -

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btn-primary').click(function () {
            $('.btn-primary').removeClass('currentButton')
            $(this).addClass('currentButton')
            $('form').hide()
            $("#form_" + $(this).attr('id')).show()
            $.get('/emailservlet', function (responseJson) {
                var $select = $('#yes');
                $select.find('option').remove();
                $.each(responseJson, function (key, value) {
                    $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($select);
                });
            });
            $.get('/itemsservlet', function (responseJson) {
                var $input = $('#id1');
                var $type = 'checkbox';
                $.each(responseJson, function (key, value) {
                    var append = $('<input type="' + $type + '">' + value + '</input>').attr('id', key).val(key);
                    $($input).append('<br/>').append(append);
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Each email id is responsible for multiple items. Meaning `abc@gmail.com` is responsible for item whose id's are for exaample `1000`, `1001`, `1002`.
In general, as soon as I select any email id, I will make an ajax call to the database to get the list of item id's this email is responsible for.

Now what I need to do is, As soon as I select `abc@gmail.com` from the drop down list, I need to check those ITEM's in the checkbox list whose id's are `1000`, `1001` and `1002`

For example, getting items from a database such as, `select items from table1 where email ='abc@gmail.com'` will give all the item id's whose email was `abc@gmail.com`, Now in my jsp page when I select any email, it should check the items based on that email if from a database?

Is this possible to do?

**Update:-**

This is the way I am sending data -

```
List<String> permission_given = new ArrayList<String>();
String permissions = null;
while (rs.next()) {
    permissions = rs.getString("permissions");
    // here permissions has id's like this 1000,1001,1002
}

permission_given = Arrays.asList(permissions.split(","));
String json = new Gson().toJson(permission_given);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML code after the `$.get`'s are finished. Because you are not actually having any problems with the servlet or the http requests this seems to be only a JQuery problem.

Comment: Thank you @ug_, you are right,I basically do not have any problem with the code I posted, it is very well getting populated from the above code, but my question is for another step, where I need to take the use of populated email drop down and query database to get the list of items. Once I have the list of items(which would be within those items that is populated in my items checkbox list), I need to dynamically `check` them.. Hope I am clear, If I am please let me know how should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a listener to your select drop down, when it changes just requery your DB to repopulate the checkbox container.

You will need to make a 3rd method in your servlet I called it `email_itemsservlet`. This method will take in an email address and send back the id's that it has, essentially running th is query (`select items from table1 where email ='abc@gmail.com'`). Upon receiving these ids you go through each of the checkboxes and either uncheck or check them if they exist in the response.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn-primary').click(function () {
        $('.btn-primary').removeClass('currentButton')
        $(this).addClass('currentButton')
        $('form').hide()
        $("#form_" + $(this).attr('id')).show()
        $.get('/emailservlet', function (responseJson) {
            var $select = $('#yes');
            $select.find('option').remove();
            $.each(responseJson, function (key, value) {
                $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($select);
            });
        });

        $.get('/itemsservlet', function (responseJson) {
            var $input = $('#id1');
            var $type = 'checkbox';
            $.each(responseJson, function (key, value) {
                var append = $('<input type="' + $type + '">' + value + '</input>').attr('id', key).val(key);
                $($input).append('<br/>').append(append);
            });
        });

        /**
            Add Change listener
        */

        $(document).on('change', '#yes', function() {
            var emailValue = $('#yes').val();

            if(emailValue) {
                $.get('/email_itemsservlet', {email: emailValue}).done(function(responseJson) {
                    var $input = $('#id1');
                    var $type = 'checkbox';
                    $('input[type="'+$type+'"]', $input).each(function() {
                        if($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), responseJson) != -1) {
                            $(this).prop('checked', true);
                        } else {
                            $(this).prop('checked', false);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }); 

        /*End Changes*/

    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @ug_, Just to make sure if we are on same page, and I correctly got what we are doing here. So in my case, all the emails got  populated dynamically and also all the item id's got populated as well. Now as soon as I am selecting an email id (abc@gmail.com), I will get the list of item id's from the database using Ajax call for this email id and then I will check these item id's which we got from the database and those items id are  already present in the checkbox list. Since all the item id's already gets populated while I click Access button.

Comment: Thanks. In your change listener, you have `if(email) {` is this correct? or it should be `emailValue`?

Comment: @akiiddweeber whoops, yes it should be

Comment: Thanks! @ug_, I have one more quick question, so I have added, `alert(responseJson)`, and I am able to alert the id's as `1000,1001,1002` properly, but it is not getting checked after that? can you help me what possibly could go wrong here? Does my format of id's are wrong?

Comment: @akiiddweeber well alot of it depends on how your data is being returned. Is it a JSON array, JSON object or a list of strings delimited by commas? I assumed it was a JSON object due from your previous code but if it isnt my code wouldnt work properly. Do you know the exact datatype of your response?

Comment: I have updated the question with the way, I am sending the data to JSP? May be that is the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56494/discussion-between-ug-and-akiiddweeber).